# Minio tenant fails to connect to minio-operator and keeps crashing with timeouts

Tags: kubernetes, minio

I am trying to create a minio tenant with minio operator.

Just to test, I'm using the simplest setup I can come up with: 1 server and 4 drives.

Name of the tanant is `minio-tenant-1` and it's running on a separate namespace: `minio-tenant-1`.
I also disabled TLS, prometheus monitoring and audit logging just in case.

The pod keeps timing out with this error:

```
ERROR Unable to validate passed arguments in MINIO_ARGS:env://zUXN5Ti5QxmT4fPxwQFB:5Kt2M5omOqmN2HUB0zFAfblI7DYY5PF8OZ8kfvdC@operator.minio-operator.svc.cluster.local:4222/webhook/v1/getenv/minio-tenant-1/minio-tenant-1: Get "http://operator.minio-operator.svc.cluster.local:4222/webhook/v1/getenv/minio-tenant-1/minio-tenant-1?key=MINIO_ARGS": dial tcp: lookup operator.minio-operator.svc.cluster.local: i/o timeout
```

```
$ k describe pod/minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0 -n minio-tenant-1
Name:             minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0
Namespace:        minio-tenant-1
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             master/192.168.0.248
Start Time:       Fri, 24 Mar 2023 18:00:03 +0000
Labels:           controller-revision-hash=minio-tenant-1-pool-0-58bb9b869b
                  statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0
                  v1.min.io/console=minio-tenant-1-console
                  v1.min.io/pool=pool-0
                  v1.min.io/tenant=minio-tenant-1
Annotations:      min.io/revision: 0
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.0.29
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.29
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/minio-tenant-1-pool-0
Containers:
  minio:
    Container ID:  cri-o://47a0fc9343c38439c09b96c65c0938c0b438c4fca5beeffca8917254a1af6e83
    Image:         minio/minio:RELEASE.2023-03-22T06-36-24Z
    Image ID:      docker.io/minio/minio@sha256:02b9d0234025a31b1fb2a52697b62a18a4fbd0db03cbd83dfc09fc48773b718c
    Ports:         9000/TCP, 9090/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      server
      --certs-dir
      /tmp/certs
      --console-address
      :9090
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 24 Mar 2023 19:39:23 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 24 Mar 2023 19:39:27 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  24
    Requests:
      cpu:     4
      memory:  8Gi
    Environment:
      MINIO_ARGS:                    <set to the key 'MINIO_ARGS' in secret 'operator-webhook-secret'>  Optional: false
      MINIO_CONFIG_ENV_FILE:         /tmp/minio-config/config.env
      MINIO_OPERATOR_VERSION:        v4.5.8
      MINIO_PROMETHEUS_JOB_ID:       minio-job
      MINIO_SERVER_URL:              http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local:80
      MINIO_UPDATE:                  on
      MINIO_UPDATE_MINISIGN_PUBKEY:  RWTx5Zr1tiHQLwG9keckT0c45M3AGeHD6IvimQHpyRywVWGbP1aVSGav
    Mounts:
      /export0 from data0 (rw)
      /export1 from data1 (rw)
      /export2 from data2 (rw)
      /export3 from data3 (rw)
      /tmp/minio-config from configuration (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-j468h (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  data0:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data0-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  data1:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data1-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  data2:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data2-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  data3:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data3-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  configuration:
    Type:                Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    SecretName:          minio-tenant-1-env-configuration
    SecretOptionalName:  <nil>
  kube-api-access-j468h:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                    ----     -------
  Warning  BackOff  2m52s (x456 over 102m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container minio in pod minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0_minio-tenant-1(fbe54e33-bb94-4332-aa4b-ebb05277884e)
```

The node affinity for now is set to master, but I have other nodes that I could disperse the drives on. My understanding is that it shouldn't matter (but I might be wrong):

```
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - master
```

pv and pvc seem in order as well:

```
$ k get pv
NAME         CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                          STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
minio-pv-1   6Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    minio-tenant-1/data2-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0   local-storage            123m
minio-pv-2   6Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    minio-tenant-1/data1-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0   local-storage            123m
minio-pv-3   6Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    minio-tenant-1/data0-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0   local-storage            123m
minio-pv-4   6Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    minio-tenant-1/data3-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0   local-storage            123m
$ k get pvc
NAME                            STATUS   VOLUME       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS    AGE
data0-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0   Bound    minio-pv-3   6Gi        RWO            local-storage   122m
data1-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0   Bound    minio-pv-2   6Gi        RWO            local-storage   122m
data2-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0   Bound    minio-pv-1   6Gi        RWO            local-storage   122m
data3-minio-tenant-1-pool-0-0   Bound    minio-pv-4   6Gi        RWO            local-storage   122m
$
```

The DNS resolution is fine as well:

```
$ k exec -it nginx-56b884b9cf-mz49v -n minio-tenant-1 -- sh
# curl -k http://operator.minio-operator.svc.cluster.local:4222
404 page not found
```

minio operator seems alive and I can access the console interface to create the tenant:

```
$ k -n minio-operator get all
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/console-56f9795d5c-48lxd          1/1     Running   0          16h
pod/minio-operator-86d96956d6-9z4ll   1/1     Running   0          150m
pod/minio-operator-86d96956d6-t6pdh   1/1     Running   0          151m

NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
service/console    ClusterIP   10.106.35.184    <none>        9090/TCP,9443/TCP   16h
service/operator   ClusterIP   10.100.234.145   <none>        4222/TCP,4221/TCP   150m

NAME                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/console          1/1     1            1           16h
deployment.apps/minio-operator   2/2     2            2           16h

NAME                                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/console-56f9795d5c          1         1         1       16h
replicaset.apps/minio-operator-7cd6784f59   0         0         0       16h
replicaset.apps/minio-operator-86d96956d6   2         2         2       15h
```

The minio operator logs:

```
$ k -n minio-operator logs -f pod/minio-operator-86d96956d6-t6pdh
I0324 19:54:05.667811       1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Tenant", Namespace:"minio-tenant-1", Name:"minio-tenant-1", UID:"0b1bfd35-1cf9-4328-b95a-d41e6516ad1f", APIVersion:"minio.min.io/v2", ResourceVersion:"348247", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'UsersCreatedFailed' Users creation failed: Put "http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local/minio/admin/v3/add-user?accessKey=0k95Hbreiyn4qor1": dial tcp 10.99.200.221:80: connect: connection refused
I0324 19:55:01.181291       1 monitoring.go:129] 'minio-tenant-1/minio-tenant-1' Failed to get cluster health: Get "http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local/minio/health/cluster": dial tcp 10.99.200.221:80: connect: connection refused
I0324 19:55:04.199435       1 monitoring.go:129] 'minio-tenant-1/minio-tenant-1' Failed to get cluster health: Get "http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local/minio/health/cluster": dial tcp 10.99.200.221:80: connect: connection refused
E0324 19:55:05.725779       1 main-controller.go:618] error syncing 'minio-tenant-1/minio-tenant-1': Put "http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local/minio/admin/v3/add-user?accessKey=0k95Hbreiyn4qor1": dial tcp 10.99.200.221:80: connect: connection refused
I0324 19:55:05.725797       1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Tenant", Namespace:"minio-tenant-1", Name:"minio-tenant-1", UID:"0b1bfd35-1cf9-4328-b95a-d41e6516ad1f", APIVersion:"minio.min.io/v2", ResourceVersion:"348247", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'UsersCreatedFailed' Users creation failed: Put "http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local/minio/admin/v3/add-user?accessKey=0k95Hbreiyn4qor1": dial tcp 10.99.200.221:80: connect: connection refused
I0324 19:55:09.428632       1 monitoring.go:129] 'minio-tenant-1/minio-tenant-1' Failed to get cluster health: Get "http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local/minio/health/cluster": dial tcp 10.99.200.221:80: connect: connection refused
I0324 19:55:17.817331       1 monitoring.go:129] 'minio-tenant-1/minio-tenant-1' Failed to get cluster health: Get "http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local/minio/health/cluster": dial tcp 10.99.200.221:80: connect: connection refused
E0324 19:56:05.828596       1 main-controller.go:618] error syncing 'minio-tenant-1/minio-tenant-1': Put "http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local/minio/admin/v3/add-user?accessKey=0k95Hbreiyn4qor1": dial tcp 10.99.200.221:80: connect: connection refused
I0324 19:56:05.828627       1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Tenant", Namespace:"minio-tenant-1", Name:"minio-tenant-1", UID:"0b1bfd35-1cf9-4328-b95a-d41e6516ad1f", APIVersion:"minio.min.io/v2", ResourceVersion:"348247", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'UsersCreatedFailed' Users creation failed: Put "http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local/minio/admin/v3/add-user?accessKey=0k95Hbreiyn4qor1": dial tcp 10.99.200.221:80: connect: connection refused
E0324 19:57:05.900952       1 main-controller.go:618] error syncing 'minio-tenant-1/minio-tenant-1': Put "http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local/minio/admin/v3/add-user?accessKey=0k95Hbreiyn4qor1": dial tcp 10.99.200.221:80: connect: connection refused
I0324 19:57:05.901063       1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Tenant", Namespace:"minio-tenant-1", Name:"minio-tenant-1", UID:"0b1bfd35-1cf9-4328-b95a-d41e6516ad1f", APIVersion:"minio.min.io/v2", ResourceVersion:"348247", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'UsersCreatedFailed' Users creation failed: Put "http://minio.minio-tenant-1.svc.cluster.local/minio/admin/v3/add-user?accessKey=0k95Hbreiyn4qor1": dial tcp 10.99.200.221:80: connect: connection refused
```

```
$ k get netpol -A
No resources found
```

```
$ k minio version
v4.5.8
```

Ripping my hair right now, I'm sure I am missing something ridiculously stupid. Will greatly appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This issue got solved in verion 5.x.x of MinIO Operator as it no longer uses webhook to obtain the MINIO_ARGS but rather there is a sidecar that provide those arguments and it does not fail this way.
Please try with latest Operator version available.
Setting this comment as Community wiki for people to improve accordingly.